# angular 2 on from submit error self.context.onSubmit is not a function

Tags: forms, angular, form-submit, onsubmit

I am using 2.0.0-rc.6 in my angular 2 application.
on form submit I am getting this error - ***self.context.onSubmit is not a function***

[image]

also it is appending form values in browser.

http://localhost:3000/register

on submit  the page reloading and url become like this.

http://localhost:3000/register?firstName=vcvvc&lastName=vcv&userName=cvv&password=vcv&password=vcv

the codes are

**form**

```
<form class="ui form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #registrationForm="ngForm">
----
----
 <button type="submit" class="ui button"> Register</button>
    </form>
```

**the service**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { RegisterService } from '../services/register.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'side-panel',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/register.component.html'
})
export class RegisterComponent { 

    newuser: User = new User();
    theText: string;

    constructor(private _registerService: RegisterService){ 
    }

    onsubmit(){
        console.log('form submit clicked..');
        this._registerService.sendUser(this.newuser).subscribe(
            date =>{
                this.newuser = new User();
            },
            error => console.log(error)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember javascript is case-sensitive. Your function should be renamed to `onSubmit` instead of `onsubmit`.

Comment: ohh,OMG, this is problem late night coding :-).Thanks Harry

Comment: Same issue for me, but I called the function ngSubmit instead of onSubmit!

Answer (score 10):

***This error occurs when the name of the methods called in an event not matched with the template declaration and inside the class***

In your template you have specified **onSubmit()** as camel case

```js
<form class="ui form" (ngSubmit)="**onSubmit()**" #registrationForm="ngForm">
```

but inside the class, its not a camelCase "**onsubmit()"**

```js
 onsubmit(){
        console.log('form submit clicked..');
        this._registerService.sendUser(this.newuser).subscribe(
```