# inline template:1:1 caused by: self.context.onSubmit is not a function getting error angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Getting error while submiting my form.

login.component.html:

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
    <form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" class="user name" placeholder="Enter user name" name="username" [(ngModel)]="userName"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
        <div *ngIf="errorMessage" class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Login error!</strong> Invalid credentails.
    </div>
</div>
```

login.component.ts:

```
export class LoginComponent {

  loginForm:FormGroup;
  private sub:any
  userName:string;
  password:string;

  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private loginService:LoginService,private router:Router) { }

    onSubmit(value:any){
      console.log('form submit clicked');
    console.log(this.userName,this.password);

    this.loginService.login(this.userName,this.password).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);

    },error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);


  }

}
```

I tried all the possible ways .
This [angular 2 on from submit error self.context.onSubmit is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432192/angular-2-on-from-submit-error-self-context-onsubmit-is-not-a-function) link also not solving my problem .
Please guys look into this.

Comment: Can you reproduce in Plunker or https://stackblitz.com ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer unable to create sample plunker man

Comment: Unable to create a Plunker, or unable to reproduce the issue in Plunker?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  unable to reproduce the issue in plunker.you can find the code from here . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4xdqk?file=app%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.html

Comment: Did you use the "share" feature to create the stackblitz link? It doesn't seem to contain the code from your question.

Comment: you can find in app/login folder structure

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, but the code doesn't execute. I can't reproduce https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4xdqk. Have you tried restarting `ng serve`?

Comment: No i am doing now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154319/discussion-between-ajay-and-gunter-zochbauer).