# Angular 4 Error TypeError, ERROR Context

Tags: javascript, angular, http, typescript

I am getting the TypeError and Context Error from my code. I have looked at these stack questions:

[Angular 4 - ERROR TypeError, ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879095/angular-4-error-typeerror-error-context-debugcontext)

[angular 2 on from submit error self.context.onSubmit is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432192/angular-2-on-from-submit-error-self-context-onsubmit-is-not-a-function)

I cannot find the issue within my code. The error is as follows

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at UnlockComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/unlock/unlock.component.ts.UnlockComponent.unlock (unlock.component.ts:252)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (UnlockComponent.html:81)
    at handleEvent (core.es5.js:12022)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13486)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:13074)
    at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8615)
    at core.es5.js:9226
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.es5.js:2651)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
```

and

```
UnlockComponent.html:81 ERROR CONTEXT 
DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 120, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
component
:
(...)
componentRenderElement
:
(...)
context
:
(...)
elDef
:
{index: 120, parent: {…}, renderParent: {…}, bindingIndex: 12, outputIndex: 6, …}
elOrCompView
:
(...)
elView
:
{def: {…}, parent: {…}, viewContainerParent: null, parentNodeDef: {…}, context: UnlockComponent, …}
injector
:
(...)
nodeDef
:
{index: 120, parent: {…}, renderParent: {…}, bindingIndex: 12, outputIndex: 6, …}
nodeIndex
:
120
providerTokens
:
(...)
references
:
(...)
renderNode
:
(...)
view
:
{def: {…}, parent: {…}, viewContainerParent: null, parentNodeDef: {…}, context: UnlockComponent, …}
__proto__
:
Object
```

The error is referring to this HTML line:

```
    <button class="btn-primary" (click)="unlock()">
      Yes
    </button>
```

and this function in my component.ts file:

```
unlock() {
    let observer = {
      next(data) {
        data => console.log(data)
      },
      error(error) {
        return new Error('Post Error');
      },
      complete() {
        console.log("Completed");
        // window.location.reload();
      }
    };
    // On unlock send lock data to Service for POST
    this.http.postUnlock(this.unlocked).subscribe(observer);
  }
```

which refers to a service.ts function:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, URLSearchParams, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()

export class apiService {
  // SET URL STRING FOR API CALL
  // url: string = 'https://ineowebm7.azurewebsites.net/api/UnlockApis';
  url: string = 'https://portal2.ineotech.com/ineoM7reference/api/UnlockApis';
  body: Array<any> = [];

  // SET HTTP TO PRIVATE
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  // GET LOCK RESOURCES
  getLocked() {
    // set observable
    return this.http.get(this.url).map((res) => res.json());
  }

  // POST to UNLOCK RESOURCES
  postUnlock(locked) {
    return locked.forEach((lock) => {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append( 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      let newBody = JSON.stringify(lock);
      let auth = lock.AuthID;
      let form = lock.FormName;
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: 'post', body: newBody });
      let newUrl = this.url + `?authid=${auth}&formname=${form}`;
      console.log(newUrl);
      // POST to URL
      return this.http.post(newUrl, options).map((res )=> res.json());
    });
  }

}
```

I have made sure the function in the component and the `(click)` are the same and not misspelled.

Has anyone seen this before or could point out the issue to what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: It might be that this.unlocked is an empty object so in apiService .postUnlock() the http.post is never getting returned.