# Ionic3 testing : TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, karma-jasmine

I'am developping an app and while testing it with Jasmine and Karma I get this error but only for one page :

> > TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
> >                 at new Content (webpack:///node_modules/ionic-angular/components/content/content.js:218:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:37929:57)
> >                 at createClass (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:12174:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:12443:20)
> >                 at createDirectiveInstance (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:12011:21 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:12280:37)
> >                 at createViewNodes (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13449:37 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:13718:53)
> >                 at callViewAction (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13881:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:14150:13)
> >                 at execComponentViewsAction (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13790:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:14059:13)
> >                 at createViewNodes (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13477:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:13746:5)
> >                 at createRootView (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13339:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:13608:5)
> >                 at callWithDebugContext (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14740:25 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:15009:42)
> >                 at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14041:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:14310:12)
> >                 at ComponentFactory_.create (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:10960:25 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:11229:46)
> >                 at initComponent (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js:1086:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:46617:49)
> >                 at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:163677:26)
> >                 at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:166578:39)
> >                 at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:163676:32)
> >                 at Object.onInvoke (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4629:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:4898:33)
> >                 at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:163676:32)
> >                 at Zone.run (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:142:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:163427:43)
> >                 at NgZone.run (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4446:47 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:4715:69)
> >                 at TestBed.createComponent (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js:1089:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:46620:58)
> >                 at Function.TestBed.createComponent (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js:808:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:46339:29)
> >                 at UserContext.beforeEach (webpack:///src/pages/list-master/list-master.spec.ts:48:20<- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:188450:82)
> >                 at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:163677:26)
> >                 at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:166578:39)
> >                 at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:163676:32)
> >                 at Zone.run (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:142:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:163427:43)
> >                 at UserContext. (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:104:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:166786:34)
> >                 at webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js:93:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:45624:17
> >                 at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:163677:26)
> >                 at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:49:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:166876:39)
> >                 at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:76:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:166575:39)
> >                 at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:163676:32)
> >                 at Zone.run (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:142:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:163427:43)
> >                 at AsyncTestZoneSpec._finishCallback (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js:88:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:45619:25)
> >                 at webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:38:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:166865:31
> >                 at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:425:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:163710:31)
> >                 at Zone.runTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:163477:47)
> >                 at ZoneTask.invokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:499:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:163784:34)
> >                 at ZoneTask.invoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:488:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:163773:48)
> >                 at timer (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:2040:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:165325:29)

I tried the solutions offered by the following topics :

- [same problem as mine at first sight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942482/karma-typeerror-cannot-read-property-subscribe-of-undefined)
- [same error but not testing its app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552766/angular-4-error-typeerror-error-context/46552801?noredirect=1#comment80061112_46552801)

I'm new to AngularJS and Ionic in general so I don't have much experience. 
I did some mocks to provide for my spec file as you can see here :

```
describe('Page : ListMaster', () => {
    let fixture;
    let component;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ListMasterPage],
        imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(ListMasterPage)
        ],
        providers: [
            { provide: StatusBar, useClass: StatusBarMock },
            { provide: SplashScreen, useClass: SplashScreenMock },
            { provide: Platform, useClass: PlatformMock },
            { provide: NavController, useClass: NavMock },
            { provide: NavParams, useClass: NavMock },
            { provide: Games, useClass: GamesMock },
            { provide: User, useClass: UserMock },
            { provide: Tracking, useClass: TrackingMock },
            { provide: ViewController, useClass:ViewControllerMock },
            LocalNotifications,
        ]
    })
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListMasterPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
});
it('Est créé', () => {
    expect(component instanceof ListMasterPage).toBe(true);
});
it('appel fonction scrollToCurrentLevel', () => {
    let subscribeEl = fixture.platform.resume.subscribe();
    expect(fixture.scrollToCurrentLevel).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

And here is the ionViewDidLoad of my list-master.ts file that creates the error ( well at least I guess it comes from here) :

```
    ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
            this.user.setCreditsBack(3).then((response: any) => {
                this.credits = this.user.getCreditsNb();
            }).catch(err => {
                let toastCreditErreur = this.toastCtrl.create({
                    message: 'erreur de recreditation',
                    duration: 3000,
                    position: 'middle'
                });
                toastCreditErreur.present();
                console.log(err);
            });
        });
    });
```

If anyone had an idea of what this error is about and could help me it would be great ! 
Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding :

```
public writeReady = {
        subscribe() {

        }
```

in my ViewControllerMock